# How to dispatch an event at given coordinates in tizen

Tags: events, tizen, dispatch, tizen-native-app

I want to dispatch a touch event automatically in a Tizen app without user interaction.
I have used `dispatchevent()` method but it requires an HTML element to trigger the event.

Also I have used `generatetouch()` method in Tizen native app but it requires platform level signed key, which I am not able to get.

So how van I simulate a touch event in Tizen IDE??

Answer (score 0):

You can use platform level privilege at the Tizen IDE Emulator.

Check below link.

https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.gettingstarted/html/tizen_overview/platform_privileges.htm

:)